# Build Windows Phone app picking appropriate assets based on the build configuration selected

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, c#-5.0

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 application which i have to provide for around 40 clients.
Each client will have specific data and UI which i will be processing and creating  from a Zip file i create for each client.

Now with single code base i want to generate build for each client with appropriate ZIP and other resources.(like app icons and splash )

How do i do that ?

Xcode supports this feature by multiple targets.How do i achive the same with visual studio ?

i would need to have Client specific resources which includes Zip File,app Icons and splash to go into the build by selecting the Client Specific configuration ( May be Build configuration created for each client)

simply generate build with client specific data.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For achieving my purpose i used MSBuild with required options for generating build.Created a Windows Forms application with Simple UI to Select a client.Managed the resources specific to client by replacing the existing resources with resources specific to Client Selected..